Class-based functions: Invalid template name in 'extends' tag from the 'layout_path' variable
I downloaded a free template and now I'm trying to make some functions. It has class-based functions. And now I'm trying to make login function and it shows Invalid template name in 'extends' tag: ". Got this from the 'layout_path' variable.
views.py
from web_project.template_helpers.theme import TemplateHelper
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from web_project import TemplateLayout

class AuthView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = TemplateLayout.init(self, super().get_context_data(**kwargs))

        context.update(
            {
                "layout_path": TemplateHelper.set_layout("layout_blank.html", context),
            }
        )

        return context

class LoginView(AuthView):
    template_name = 'auth_login_basic.html'
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        users = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if len(users):
            for user in users:
                if password == user.password:
                    request.session['login_info'] = {'username': user.username, 'userrole': user.userrole}
                    print(1)
                    return redirect('/dashboard/')
                else:
                    warn = "Invalid credentials"
                    messages.success(request, f'{warn}')
                    return redirect("/auth/login/")
        if users is None:
            warn = "Invalid credentials"
            messages.success(request, f'{warn}')
            return redirect('/auth/login/')
        else:
            return redirect("/dashboard/")


urls.py
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("auth/login/", LoginView.as_view(), name="auth-login-basic"),
]

The template already has this url which is working. It just renders the template. So how about if I add the above login function? I'm a little lost here. I don't know how to solve this one, it's my first time using class-based function.
path("auth/login/", AuthView.as_view(template_name="auth_login_basic.html"), name="auth-login-basic")


Share your definition of "layout_blank.html". extends is a builtin Django template tag. So the issue is coming from the use of extends in "layout_blank.html".
